# Limit bash while loop to 10 retries

Tags: bash

How can this while loop be limited to maximum 10 retries?

```
#!/bin/sh
while ! test -d /somemount/share/folder
do
    echo "Waiting for mount /somemount/share/folder..."
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: `((x++));if [[ x -eq 10 ]];then break;fi`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keep a counter:

```
#!/bin/sh

while ! test -d /somemount/share/folder
do
    echo "Waiting for mount /somemount/share/folder..."
    ((c++)) && ((c==10)) && break
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Could do `((c++)) && ((c==10)) && break` and remove the `c=1`

Comment: If you're not going to declare and/or unset the variable `c`, then you should consider putting the entire loop in a sub-shell or a function.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a `for` loop and exit it on success:

```
for try in {1..10} ; do
    [[ -d /somemount/share/folder ]] && break
done
```

The problem (which exists in the other solutions, too) is that once the loop ends, you don't know how it ended - was the directory found, or was the counter exhausted?

Comment: Won't this just do the same ?How do you know how it ended with your answer ?

Comment: @Jidder: It will. That's why I used "also" and "too".

Comment: ahh right, misread, sorry! You could add `[[ -d /somemount/share/folder ]] && break && echo "successfully mounted"` to solve it though :)

Comment: @user3442743 - the break have to be the last, otherwise it will not print (i.e. `[[ condition ]] && echo "Passed" && break`

Answer (score 6):

I would comment but I do not have enough points for that. I want to contribute anyway.
So this makes it work even if the while loop is nested in another loop. before the break the c variable is being reset to zero.
credits to @anubhava who came up with the original solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

while ! test -d /somemount/share/folder
do
    echo "Waiting for mount /somemount/share/folder..."
    ((c++)) && ((c==10)) && c=0 && break
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `until` (instead of "*while ! ... break*), with a counter limit:

```
COUNT=0
ATTEMPTS=10
until [[ -d /somemount/share/folder ]] || [[ $COUNT -eq $ATTEMPTS ]]; do
  echo -e "$(( COUNT++ ))... \c"
  sleep 1
done
[[ $COUNT -eq $ATTEMPTS ]] && echo "Could not access mount" && (exit 1)
```

Notes:

- Just like setting counter as variable, you can set var `condition="[[ .. ]]"`, and use `until eval $condition` to make it more generic.
- echo $(( COUNT++ )) increases the counter while printing.
- If running inside a function, use "return 1" instead of "exit 1".